# How to display Percentage instead of values on bar chart in CDE Pentaho?

Tags: charts, bar-chart, pentaho, pentaho-cde, pentaho-report-designer

I have below query output :

```
ConditionCount   MenberCount
       0            20
       1             5
       2             3
       3+           11
```

And I have to create a bar chart in CDE Pentaho like this :

[image]

So, How to show this percentage on bar chart?
I have tried "`valuesMask :  {value.percent}` and `Stacked : true`" But Its giving the 100% value on each bar.

Is there any way to show the percentage on bars?
And also I need to know, how should change the color of each bar?

Currently my chart looks like :

[image]

Can anyone have the solution for this?
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

In the bar chart property enable Stacked option and then valuemask as {value.percent}

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of Bars, use this code on 'Pre Execution' - advanced property :

```
function changeBars() { 
    var cccOptions = this.chartDefinition; 
    var eps = Dashboards.propertiesArrayToObject (cccOptions.extensionPoints); 
    eps.bar_fillStyle = function getColor () { 
    var val = this.scene.atoms.category.label; 
    if(val == 0) 
          {return 'red';} 
    else if(val == 1) 
          {return 'blue';} 
    else
          {return '#F77C02';} 
}; 
cccOptions.extensionPoints = Dashboards.objectToPropertiesArray (eps); 
}
```